# How to get the content of html by htmlcxx?

Tags: c++, html

I replace  the html="Chinese web page content", i cant't compile it. it's failed and i want to know how i can compile successfully and get the content when i input anyone of id,class,tag name or name.

```
#include <htmlcxx/html/ParserDom.h>
...
using namespace std;
using namespace htmlcxx;

//Parse some html code

string html = "<html><body>hey</body></html>";
HTML::ParserDom parser;
tree<HTML::Node> dom = parser.parseTree(html);

//Print whole DOM tree

cout << dom << endl;

//Dump all links in the tree

tree<HTML::Node>::iterator it = dom.begin();
tree<HTML::Node>::iterator end = dom.end();
for (; it != end; ++it)
{
 if (strcasecmp(it->tagName().c_str(), "A") == 0)
 {
   it->parseAttributes();
   cout << it->attribute("href").second << endl;
 }
}

//Dump all text of the document
it = dom.begin();
end = dom.end();
for (; it != end; ++it)
{
 if ((!it->isTag()) && (!it->isComment()))
 {
  cout << it->text();
 }
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: There is not enough information to solve this problem.

Comment: I just want to get the web page content like following code

Comment: <tag class="" or id="" or name="">content</tag> I hope that through the label or label attribute for the content of the label